# error when manipulate instance name of Tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

i dont know why get error when trying to manipulate an variable of tkinter widgets:
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pack'**
im trying to make a sieres of entry names so if my basic name is A the next names will be: 
 A_1 ,A_2,A_3.....here is my code need help

```
def generate_fieldes(x):
    generated_frame='frame1_'+x
    print generated_frame
    A_generated   ='A_'+x
    B_generated   ='B_'+x
    C_generated   ='C_'+x
    D_generated   ='D_'+x
    E_generated  ='E_'+x
    F_generated   ='F_'+x
    if frame1.winfo_exists()==1:

        generated_frame=Frame(tab1,height=200,width=600,bg='yellow')
        A_generated = AutocompleteEntry(list, generated_frame,bd =2,width=26,justify=RIGHT)


        A_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)
        A_generated.focus_set()        

        B_generated = Entry(generated_frame, bd =2,width=12,justify=RIGHT)
        B_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)
        C_generated = Entry(generated_frame, bd =2,width=12,justify=RIGHT)
        C_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)
        D_generated = Entry(generated_frame, bd =2,width=17,justify=RIGHT)
        D_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)
        E_generated = Entry(generated_frame, bd =2,width=17,justify=RIGHT)
        E_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)
        F_generated = Entry(generated_frame, bd =2,width=20,justify=RIGHT)
        F_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)   
        generated_frame.pack(fill=X,side=TOP)

generate_fields('1')
```

Comment: `A_generated` is only a string, and a string doesn't have the method `pack`.

Comment: ok i do inderstand and i am asking how make it without error

Comment: as you see above for example A_generated has the 'pack' method and its supposed to be Entry

Comment: list is a List of names assigned to autocomplete entry,btw the error is apparing with all Entries not just A_x

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: It seems you are trying to create variables named A_1, B_1, etc. Are you aware that's not happening? You can't generate variables this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
A_generated = Entry(generated_frame, bd =2,width=12,justify=RIGHT)
A_generated.pack(side = RIGHT)
A_generated.focus_set()
```

In your current code, you didn't declare `A_generated` as an instance of `Entry`, but a string.

Comment: yes i mistyped A1_generated  INSTEAD of A_generated ;but still have the error even after correcting

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Probably you just saved it :)

Answer (score 0):

> ...im trying to make a sieres of entry names ...

You can't, and shouldn't, do that. Generated variable names are almost always more trouble than they are worth. You may *think* you're creating variables named A_1, B_1, etc, but you are merely reassigning A_generated. First, A_generated is the string "A_1", and then you change it to be whatever the widget name is. You do *not* end up with a variable named A_1 that points to a widget.

If you want to create references to your widgets based on the value of the variable `x`, you should use a dictionary. For example:

```
A[x] = Entry(...)
B[x] = Entry(...)
```

With that, `A[1]` will refer to a widget, as will `B[1]`, and so on. (though you must first create a global variable named A, B, etc).